# Converting string to java type

Tags: java, string, class

I have the following code and I need to convert my string o1 & o2 (input by the user) into the Fraction class f1 & f2. I'm not sure how to do this and any help would be appreciated!

Update: Setters and getters are already in place, I only pasted the relevant aspects of the code in here. Everything works but I don't know how to assign f1 a value (the value of which should be o1).

```
private int numerator;
private int denominator;
public Fraction(){
    numerator = 0;
    denominator = 1;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    String o1 = null;
    String o2 = null;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Input Operand 1, separate numerator and denominator by '/'.");
    o1 = scan.next();
    System.out.println("Input Operand 2, separate numerator and denominator by '/'.");
    o2 = scan.next();

    Fraction f1 = new Fraction();
    int n1 = f1.getNumerator();
    int d1 = f1.getDenominator();
    Fraction f2 = new Fraction();
    int n2 = f2.getNumerator();
    int d2 = f2.getDenominator();

    Fraction A = new Fraction(n1, d1);
    Fraction B = new Fraction(n2,d2);
    A.printF(add(A,B));
    A.printF(sub(A,B));
    A.printF(multiply(A,B));
    A.printF(divide(A,B));      
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java

Comment: Need more details... user enters, e.g. "2/5" and you want to create a "Fraction" with numerator 2 and denominator 5 and "Fraction" is your own class?  Apache's NumberUtils has methods to do String to int, but what you'll want to do is split the input on "/" to get numerator and denominator...and then store those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood correctly...

### First step: splitting at the slash

```
String[] o1Parts = o1.split("/");
String[] o2Parts = o2.split("/");
```

### Second step: converting to int

```
int o1Numerator = Integer.parseInt(o1Parts[0]);
int o1Denominator = Integer.parseInt(o1Parts[1]);

int o2Numerator = Integer.parseInt(o2Parts[0]);
int o2Denominator = Integer.parseInt(o2Parts[1]);
```

### Third and last step: creating the `Fraction` object

```
Fraction o1Fraction = new Fraction(o1Numerator, o1Denominator);
Fraction o2Fraction = new Fraction(o2Numerator, o2Denominator);
```

In case the class doesn't have this constructor, but only setters:

```
Fraction o1Fraction = new Fraction();
o1Fraction.setNumerator(o1Numerator);
o1Fraction.setDenominator(o1Denominator);

Fraction o2Fraction = new Fraction();
o2Fraction.setNumerator(o2Numerator);
o2Fraction.setDenominator(o2Denominator);
```

### Caveats

Please mind that this code does no input validation, so if you write something that is not `number/number`, it'll break. Also, I did not compile to test it, so there may be one or two syntax errors hiding in there, but this is the basic idea.

Comment: This is what I was saying in my comment, but the requirements were somewhat unclear.  This is a good solution, assuming the requirements are what it seems.

Answer (score 1):

You can separator the String on basis of '/' and set the value of numerator of denomerator attribute of class Fraction as below :

```
        String o1 = "10/5";
        Fraction f1 = new Fraction();
        f1.setNumerator(Integer.parseInt(o1.substring(0,o1.indexOf("/"))));
        f1.setDenomerator(Integer.parseInt(o1.substring(o1.indexOf("/")+1)));
```

I don't find the `setter` and `getter` for the attribute,create it and set the value with above code.